# R XPATH strings contains element from a list

Tags: r, xpath, xpathsapply

I m using R and the xpathSApply function to get elements from a web page that contains specific strings.
I m trying to use the contains function from xpath with several elements I stored in a list called my_list.

```
my_list <- c("word1", "word2", "word3")
xpathSApply(doc, "//h2[contains(text(),'paste(my_list, collapse='|')')]")
```

For now it doesn't work, so I divided it into several lines:

```
xpathSApply(doc, "//h2[contains(text(),'word1')]")
xpathSApply(doc, "//h2[contains(text(),'word2')]")
xpathSApply(doc, "//h2[contains(text(),'word3')]")
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match node that contains one of substrings you can try

```
"//h2[contains(text(),'word1') or contains(text(),'word2') or contains(text(),'word3')]"
```